# Windows 7 Style in Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf

Whenever I insert the Aero.NormalColor.xaml into my resource dictionary, the only way the program is able to run is through debug mode.  If it removed, I can run with debugging and without.  Any reason?  Here is my App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="HTA.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary/Miscellaneous.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionary/ListControls.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero;component/themes/Aero.NormalColor.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed set the Copy Local property to true for PresentationFramework.Aero.